# Invariant Polynomes under group action - given the invariants looking for the group. algorithmic solution?

Tags: invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory, algorithms

I have given a finite set $S$ of polynomes in the ring $R = C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. I need to know the minimal group $G$ wich acts on $R$ such that $C[S]$ is the ring of invariants of $R$ under the action of $G$. In other words:
$C[S] = R^G$.

for example:
let $R =  C[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ and $R^G = C[ x_1 x_2 x_3, x_{1}^3,x_{2}^3,x_{3}^3 ]$

let $G \subset SL_3(C)$ act via $a e_i \mapsto a x_i$. If $\xi$ is a third primitive
root of unity, then $G$ must be generated by the
diagonal matrix($\xi,\xi,\xi$).

Does there exist an algorithem for this kind of problem? I just know some the other way round - given the group, looking for the invariants.

greatz Johannes

edit:
rewritten the problem to remove ambiguities because i mixed up ideals and rings in a very carelessly way.
edit2: fixed the example.

Comment: Ideals rarely contains $1$ but $1$ always lie in the invariant ring so  I don't understand the question.

Comment: I rewrote the problem, because i mixed up ideals and rings in a very carelessly way. I did not think about constant polynomes being invariant under the action when I wrote down the problem the first time.
Thnx Torsten for remind me about this basics ;)

greatz Johannes.


Comment: Sorry but now your example is still wrong, we have that $x_1x_2x_3$ is also invariant under your scalar matrices (you have to replace the scalar matrices with all diagonal matrices whose non-zero entries are third roots of unity).

Comment: That is a case wich could appear. I fixed the example, so that the Group and the subring fit together.